# how to create menu in android on click of list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to create menu in android .Actually I want to show delete Icon when I long press in my list item .
I tried like this .I create one **my_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/id_delete"

    android:title="Delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/delete"></item>
</menu>
```

Then I create list view .My list view is display on view but it is not showing delete icon when i press long on row .Mean I want to show menu option when I press long on row .I am able to display list..but menu is not display.

here is my java code .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList selectionList = new ArrayList();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        Log.d("==", loadJSONFromAsset());
        try {
            JSONArray js = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset());
            for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = js.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(obj.getString("name"));
            }
            //adp=new CustomAddapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_view);


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                    if (checked) {
                        selectionList.add(arrayList.get(position));
                        //  arrayList.add(arr.)
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                }
            });


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a context menu:

Register your listview for a context menu:

```
registerForContextMenu(listView);`
```

Then, to add menu items:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.your_list_view)
    {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("My menu");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Cancel");
        // etc...
    }
}
```

But as far as icons go...

> Context menus: Do not support item shortcuts and item icons.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html

However, if you search SO you can find ways to do it (code examples, links to libraries).